# passing Angular directive into jquery popover

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am trying to pass a dict (channels), which includes key/value pairs for name, and topChannelUserNames, and topChannelIds, the last 2 of which are arrays of strings.  I am seeing the correct value passed into var stream, but it is not reflecting in the channel variable which is the content of the popover. How do I properly pass stream into the channelinfo directive??

FYI, channels is populated in the scope asynchronously from a server call so it is not available when the directive is evaluated, hence the scope.$watch call.

also, the templateUrl doesnt seem to work so i am including the entire HTML template in the channelinfo directive.

HTML code:

```
<li><a popover="" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" stream="channels.comedy_talkshow" href="#/channel/comedy_talkshow">Talk Show</a></li>
```

Javascript code:

```
blissApp.directive('popover', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        stream: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        var stream;

        scope.$watch('stream', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            stream = newValue;
            console.log('attribute = ' + stream);

        var ele = angular.element("<channelinfo data='stream'></channelinfo>");            
        var channel = $compile(ele)(scope);           
        console.log('content = ' + channel);
        $(element).popover({position: 'right', trigger: 'hover', placement: "right", content: channel});
        }, true);
    }
}
});

blissApp.directive('channelinfo' , function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {data: "="},
    template: '<div style="padding:0px"> <div><span ng-repeat="thumbUrl in data.topChannelIds"> <img style="width:70px; height:70px; float:left;" src="https://i.ytimg.com/i/{{thumbUrl}}/mq1.jpg"/></span> <p style="color:#333; float:left">Including channels: <span ng-repeat="name in data.topChannelUserNames"> {{name}}<span ng-show=" ! $last ">, </span></span></p></div></div>'
    //templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
}
});
```

Comment: could you please share plunker demo or fiddle demo

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BFI2y6pBJTTyG8ZiHxPc